# ->performDeleteOnModel() on model when ->decrement() <= 0 does not fire deleting/deleted event

Tags: php, laravel, events, eloquent, listener

I'm working with a Resource pivot model between Owners and ResourceDefinition models.

When trades are made, I'm using decrement on the additional pivot "quantity" field:

```php
DB::transaction(function () use ($givenItem, $target, $quantity) {
    $target->receive($givenItem, $quantity);

    $givenItem->pivot->decrement('quantity', $quantity);
});
```

I've registered a callable function into the updating event to perform the deletion of the model (and relation):

```php
protected static function booted(): void
{
    /**
     * Because Resource is just a pivot between its owner and ResourceDefinition
     * We need to delete it when it decrease to 0
     */
    static::updating(static function (self $model) {
        if ($model->quantity <= 0) {
            Log::debug('from model');

            $model->performDeleteOnModel(); // I've also tried ->delete(), but my model is not deleted....
        }
    });
}
```

but for some kind of owner (it's a polymorphical relationship), I need to delete the owner when the quantity hit the ground, so I've created an event which should be fired when deleting the model:

```php
// In my resource model class
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'deleting' => Deleting::class
];

// My event:
class Deleting
{
    public ResourceModel $resource;

    public function __construct(ResourceModel $resource)
    {
        Log::debug('from event');

        $this->resource = $resource;
    }
}

// My listener
class DestroyAndRespawnCollectableBuilding
{
    public function handle(Deleting $event)
    {
        Log::debug('from listener');
    }
}
```

*Listener discovering is activated so I don't need to register the event (all others work fine)*

I've used log to not blow your mind with my code-logic, but the result is here, I'm trying to fire the event twice, but no log from the event or listener is registered:

```
[2020-11-01 21:24:14] local.DEBUG: from model
[2020-11-01 21:23:18] local.DEBUG: from model
```

Does someone know why this is happening?

Comment: `static::updating(` it is working?

Comment: Yep, the Log::debug from the model::updating is logged as expected.

I've discovered that performDeleteOnModel doesn't fire the deleting and deleted event. This is why I don't actually get the Event and Listener called. But Since ->delete() doesn't perform the deleted query (please don't ask me why). How to delete the pivot model and fire the events from itself?